# Multiple buttons different properties loop

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I'm setting up a windowsform that pings all my IP's at work and changes the `button.BackColor` accordingly.

```
Ping pingClassxx = new Ping();
PingReply pingxx = pingClassxx.Send("192.168.xx.xx");

if (pingxx.Status == IPStatus.Success)
{
    button1.BackColor = Color.Green;
    button1.Text = "SQL Server | Online";
}
else
{
    button1.BackColor = Color.Red;
    button1.Text = "SQL Server | Offline";
}
```

Now I'm trying to do this to multiple machines so I went like this:

```
private void timer0_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer1.Stop();

    int iCount0 = 0;
    string[] arr = new string[8];
    arr[0] = "192.168.x.xx";        //button0
    arr[1] = "192.168.x.yy";        //button1
    arr[2] = "192.168.x.zz";        //button2
    arr[3] = "192.168.x.xy";        //button3
    arr[4] = "192.168.x.xz";        //button4
    arr[5] = "192.168.x.yx";        //button5
    arr[6] = "192.168.yy.yz";       //button6
    arr[7] = "192.168.x.ww";        //button7

    for (int I = 0; I < arr.Length ; I++)
    {
        // Ping
        string s = arr[I];
        Console.WriteLine(s);

        Ping pingClassx = new Ping();
        PingReply pingx = pingClassx.Send(arr[I]);

        if (pingx.Status == IPStatus.Success)
        {
            [What do I do here?].BackColor = Color.Green;
        }
        else
        {
            [What do I do here?]BackColor = Color.Red;
        }

        // Loading Bar
        iCount2 += 1;
        progressBar0.Value = iCount2 * 100 / 8;
        label0.Text = iCount2 + "/8";
    }

    timer1.Start();
}
```

How can I loop this?

I could just repeat the code but I am sure there is a fancier way to do it.

Comment: Put your buttons in array like this Button array[] = {butt1,butt2....} then use this array to change color in loop

Comment: Do you already have all those Buttons in your Form, or you need to create them *on the fly? Do those Buttons have some use, an event handler that performs some action?

Comment: I already have all those buttons in the form, and those buttons will have use in the future... for now i just don't get how can i loop my buttons btn1, btn2...

Comment: i expected something like 
for ( i < 8 )
btn[i].BackColor = Color.Green

Comment: Simple as that, you have the solution in the first comment. Build an array using your Buttons reference, then use the array indexer to access each of them.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to Change the Color only Of Your Form Buttons then try This :

```
foreach(Button c in Form.Controls){

if (pingx.Status == IPStatus.Success)

{
    c.BackColor = Color.Green;
}
else
{
     c.BackColor = Color.Red;
}

}
```